# Toggling TableColumn.setVisible resets width, setPrefWidth doesn't change it

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, resize, tableview

I have a TableView full of nested columns.  On these columns, I have 2 context menu options -- "Hide Column" and "Unhide All Columns", which toggle the visibility of the columns and their children as such.

The tableview is populated after the UI is initialized, so the size of the columns is set to the default width, which is smaller than the size of the longest cell value.  This is what I want to happen.  I don't want the columns to extend to thousands of pixels wide because of a single particularly long entry.

My problem is this:  **when the user hides the column and unhides it, the width of that column stretches out to the smallest length possible to fit the longest cell value.  This is not what I want to happen.**  I want it to ideally keep its original width when the visibility is toggled in this way.

To solve this, I tried setting the max width to the current width before I hide the column, and then unsetting the max width and setting the prefwidth to the former maxwidth after I unhide it (thus locking it from resizing itself).  This doesn't work.

Here's an example to show what's happening.

**TestExample.java**

```
package testexample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Testexample extends Application {

    private TableView table;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //Create table
        table = new TableView();

        //Create table items
        final ObservableList<DataContainer> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            new DataContainer("Alice", "Red", "Yellow"),
            new DataContainer("Bob", "purple", "green"),
            new DataContainer("Sir Jean-Jaques-Charles III", "Deep green-cyan turqoise", "Fluorescent pink")
        );

        //Create table columns
        TableColumn nameColumn = new TableColumn("name");   
        TableColumn colorsColumn = new TableColumn("colors");
        TableColumn color1Column = new TableColumn("color1");
        TableColumn color2Column = new TableColumn("color2");

        //Make it so columns can properly display the table items
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));
        color1Column.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("color1"));
        color2Column.setCellValueFactory( new PropertyValueFactory<>("color2"));

        //Set the header context menus
        addHeaderContextMenus(nameColumn);
        addHeaderContextMenus(colorsColumn);
        addHeaderContextMenus(color1Column);
        addHeaderContextMenus(color2Column);

        //Add the columns to the table
        table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, colorsColumn);
        colorsColumn.getColumns().addAll(color1Column, color2Column);

        //Put the table inside a container
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        AnchorPane anchor = new AnchorPane();
        root.getChildren().add(anchor);
        anchor.getChildren().add(table);

        //anchor the table to the AnchorPane
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(table, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(table, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(table, 1.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(table, 1.0);

        //show the stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 300));
        primaryStage.show();

        //Add the data to the table (after everything is shown)
        table.setItems(data);
    }

    //Start the application
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //Add context menus to the headers.
    private void addHeaderContextMenus(TableColumn column) {

        //create the menu and attach the items
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
        MenuItem hideItem = new MenuItem("hide");
        MenuItem unhideAllItem = new MenuItem("unhide all");
        menu.getItems().addAll(hideItem, unhideAllItem);

        //Set behavior for hide/unhide
        hideItem.setOnAction((event) -> {
            hideColumn(column);
        });      
        unhideAllItem.setOnAction((event) -> {
            unhideAllColumns();
        });

        //attach the menu to the column (header)
        column.setContextMenu(menu);
    }

    private void hideColumn(TableColumn column) {
        column.setMaxWidth(column.getWidth());
        column.setPrefWidth(column.getWidth());
        column.setVisible(false);
    }

    private void unhideAllColumns() {
        table.getColumns().forEach(column -> {
            unhideColumnsRecursively((TableColumn)column);
        });
    }

    private void unhideColumnsRecursively(TableColumn column) {
        column.getColumns().forEach(childColumn -> {
            unhideColumnsRecursively((TableColumn)childColumn);
        });
        if(column.visibleProperty().get() == false) {
            column.setVisible(true);
            double width = column.getWidth();
            column.setMaxWidth(9999999); //arbitrarily large big number
            column.setPrefWidth(width);
            System.out.println("width to set to: " + width);
            System.out.println("current prefwidth: " + column.getPrefWidth());
            System.out.println("current actual width: " + column.getWidth());
        }
    }
}
```

**DataContainer.java**

```
package testexample;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class DataContainer {

    private final SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty color1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty color2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public DataContainer(String name, String color1, String color2) {
        this.name.set(name);
        this.color1.set(color1);
        this.color2.set(color2);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public String getColor1() {
        return color1.get();
    }

    public void setColor1(String color1) {
        this.color1.set(color1);
    }

    public String getColor2() {
        return color2.get();
    }

    public void setColor2(String color2) {
        this.color2.set(color2);
    }
}
```

Here's what the happens when I hide/unhide the name column:  [example (animated gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M9C4.gif)

Here's the output:

```
width to set to: 80.0
current prefwidth: 80.0
current actual width: 80.0
```

...which is of course not what the seems to shown, as the width is clearly longer than 80.0 after un-hiding!  This happens for all of the columns, including the "colors" parent column (in that case both color1 and color2 columns extend to the width of the longest cell value string).

Another twist:  the code actually does work *if the user makes sure to resize the column they're hiding before they hide it*.  [Example (animated gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKl3j.gif).

**So, what's going on?  Obviously the application is extending the columns to fit the longest data after the visibility is set to true.  How can I make sure that the columns maintain their former lengths?  Why does it only work after the user has resized that column (if it's setting a flag somewhere maybe I can set that flag manually?)**

Comment: I just rewrote the question so it provides MCVE.  If possible can I get this question removed from "on-hold"?  Thanks

Comment: good edit :) The "flag" is the magic 80 - if both prefWidth and width are 80, the column is auto-sized when its header is attached to the scene (aka: made visible) So the way out is to set the pref to anything != 80 on hiding. For nested columns, do it for the leaf columns (parent columns are sized to the sum of their children)

Comment: Thank you, this worked.  I set prefWidth to width + 1 on leaf nodes when hiding, and only called setVisible(true) on the highest hidden parent nodes when unhiding.  The width of all columns is maintained as I wanted it to be, and the explanation for why it was doing that makes sense.